# Exception connecting to SQL Server - execution timeout expired (shows instantly)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlclient

We are receiving the below exception when connecting to and running a stored procedure on an SQL Server.

We are connecting using the `SqlClient` in a C# application.

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

This has never happened before but is now happening to all requests.

We have no timeout set on the connection string (so would default to 30s), however the exception is thrown instantly - so I don't think it is even running the stored procedure.

We are able to connect manually to the SQL Server and run queries. There are no other reported issues.

There was a bunch of Windows updates on the SQL Server that are pending a restart, which is scheduled for tomorrow - I am hoping a restart of the server helps but would like to resolve this without having to wait until then.

Any idea why this message would be thrown instantly, and what it could mean?

Thanks

Comment: I believe connection timeout is controlled in the connection string. The error you posted is execution timeout. Those are 2 different things. Execution timeout is controlled by the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property. I say that without seeing your code. Command timeout specifies how long to wait for a query to execute before timing out. Connection timeout is how long to wait for a connection to the server before giving up. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68674652/edit) your question to include a full stack trace. The source of the exception will indicate where the problem lies.